# Hooking WH_CALLWNDPROC for Word application

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, winapi

I am trying to implement a hook filtration function for the WH_CALLWNDPROC in order to intercept messages before they reach a word application.

My code is presented below:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

''Constants Definition''
Private Const WH_CALLWNDPROC As Integer = 4
Private Const HC_ACTION As Integer = 0
Private Const WM_DESTROY As Integer = &H2
Private Const WM_ACTIVATEAPP As Integer = &H1C
Private IsHooked As Boolean
''DLL Definition
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetWindowsHookEx(idHook As Integer, callback As MyWndProcDel, hInstance As IntPtr, threadId As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(hInstance As IntPtr) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function CallNextHookEx(idHook As IntPtr, nCode As Integer, wParam As Integer, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function GetWindowThreadProcessId(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, _
                      ByRef lpdwProcessId As Integer) As Integer
End Function
    Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Integer<System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure CWPSTRUCT
    Public lParam As IntPtr
    Public wParam As IntPtr
    Public message As Integer
    Public hWnd As IntPtr
End Structure

Private fltrFunc As MyWndProcDel = AddressOf myWndProc
Private Shared lpPrevWndProc As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
Private Delegate Function MyWndProcDel(nCode As Integer, wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr 

Public Sub SetWndProcHook()
     Dim PID As Integer
     Dim WordWND  as Long
     If IsHooked Then
         MsgBox("Already Hooked")
     Else
         WordWND = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Document1")
         lpPrevWndProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, fltrFunc, Nothing,    GetWindowThreadProcessId(WordWND, PID))
        IsHooked = True
    End If
End Sub


Public Function myWndProc(ByVal ucode As Long, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    If ucode >= 0 Then
        Dim cwp As CWPSTRUCT = DirectCast(Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, GetType(CWPSTRUCT)), CWPSTRUCT)

        Select Case cwp.message
            Case WM_ACTIVATEAPP
                cwp.message = 0
                MsgBox(cwp.message)
        End Select

    Else
        CallNextHookEx(lpPrevWndProc, ucode, wParam, lParam)
    End If
  End Function
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
          SetWndProcHook()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If IsHooked Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(lpPrevWndProc)
        End If
End Sub
```

My problem is the following : 
        lpPrevWndProc = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, fltrFunc, Nothing,    GetWindowThreadProcessId(WordWND, PID))
returns 0, which means that function has executed unsuccessfully. 
GetWindowThreadProcessId(WordWND, PID)) is returning the Process ID of the opened Word application. The returned value is correct (I have checked it using Spy++ utility).
If I replace the GetWindowThreadProcessId(WordWND, PID)) by GetCurrentThreadId() I am able to hook the WH_CALLWNDPROC of the windows form I am working on. (In this case, the SetWindowsHookEx returns the handle of the hook filtration function.(Which indicates a successful execution)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Global WH_CALLWNDPROC hook requires to place HOOKPROC function to DLL pointed to by the lpfn parameter.

Comment: But this alternative has many drawbacks:
1- How can I identify the handle that the message is being sent to? (maybe the message is being sent to some other application than my word app)
2- Implementing the solution at the level of a DLL would inject the hook into all system processes, (overhead + low performance)

Comment: This is not alternative, this is requirement.

Comment: Then how can I intercept messages that are related to my word document only? (I have the handle ID, the Process ID and the thread ID)

Comment: If the target thread is in another process you must use a DLL as @AlexFarber says.